# Python: Apply an aggregating function to a variable by an aggregating dimension and select columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I assume, I have a pandas DataFrame with variables V1, V2, V3. I want to do the following aggregation procedure
    myData.groupby("V1“, as_index=False)["V2"].sum() 
and then display this result together with variable V3 (if possible in one step!). How can I do this, any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit:
From the original data frame:

```
V1    V2    V3
 1     2     4
 2     1     3
 1     4     1
```

I would like to receive:

```
V1    V2         V3
 1     **6**     4
 2     1         3
 1     **6**     1
```

So keeping V3 as it is. Can anyone help:)?

Comment: Hey, could you give us some example data and explain a bit more about how you'd like the results displayed with V3?

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**
Consider the dataframe `myData`

```
myData = pd.DataFrame(dict(V1=[1, 1, 2, 2], V2=[2] * 4, V3=[3] * 4))

   V1  V2  V3
0   1   2   3
1   1   2   3
2   2   2   3
3   2   2   3
```

---

**Option 1**
*[**`groupby` and `agg`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation)*
In my opinion, the most idiomatic way to perform this task.

```
myData.groupby('V1', as_index=False).agg('sum')

   V1  V2  V3
0   1   4   6
1   2   4   6
```

---

**Option 2**
*`set_index` and [**`sum` w/ `level`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)*
This also works but is a bit awkward with the setting and resetting of the index.

```
myData.set_index('V1').sum(level='V1').reset_index()

   V1  V2  V3
0   1   4   6
1   2   4   6
```

---

**Option 3**
*[**`np.unique`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [**`np.bincount`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)*
As a matter of perspective, we can begin to appreciate what `pandas` offers us in terms of api.  If performance is a must, you can *sometimes* (but not always) decrease your execution time but you also assume the responsibility of handling many nuances `pandas` does for you.  And again, almost always, the code is less transparent.

```
u, f = np.unique(myData.V1.values, return_inverse=True)

pd.DataFrame(dict(
        V1=u,
        V2=np.bincount(f, myData.V2.values),
        V3=np.bincount(f, myData.V3.values)
    )).astype(myData.dtypes)

   V1  V2  V3
0   1   4   6
1   2   4   6
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit myData.groupby('V1', as_index=False).agg('sum')
%timeit myData.set_index('V1').sum(level='V1').reset_index()

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 ms per loop

%%timeit
u, f = np.unique(myData.V1.values, return_inverse=True)

pd.DataFrame(dict(
        V1=u,
        V2=np.bincount(f, myData.V2.values),
        V3=np.bincount(f, myData.V3.values)
    )).astype(myData.dtypes)

1000 loops, best of 3: 654 µs per loop
```

Comment: showing numpy solutions is fine with the caveat as these generally are not dtype friendly and way more verbose for a slight perf gain

Comment: @Jeff I'm trying to show both.  I'm getting better at highlighting the dtype handling and I think the verbosity is self evident (I think).

Comment: i think it is just plain confusing to present numpy solutions in general for anything plain vanilla pandas

Comment: I'll edit this answer and I'll formulate somewhat of a script to adjoin any numpy flavored answer.

Comment: @Jeff hopefully you find the comments reasonable.

Comment: yep that looks nice

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I seem to have a different problem: I want to have V1 in the aggregated version, but all other variables with the original (not aggregated) value. So the final data frame should have an equal number of rows with the one variable in the aggregated version. Any idea about this?

Comment: @Sylvi0202 do you see how I took the time to create an example and showed the information so that there isn't ambiguity?  I'm afraid that I can't be sure what you mean unless you show me what it is you want.  That means, showing a simple example of where you are starting from and what you expect the final results to look like.  If necessary, show the logic to get from the starting point to the final result.